# Simple way to visualise word2vec vector space

Tags: python, visualization, word2vec, word-embeddings, tsne

I want to visualize my word2vec vector space (with zoom in and zoom out). I found a really interesting GitHub project named [word2vec explorer](https://github.com/dominiek/word2vec-explorer). However, it does not seem to work in windows and mac.

Hence, I am interested in knowing if there are any other off-the-shelf project I can use for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily visualize word2vec vectors using [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard), which is very easy to understand.

<sub>I have made a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkeQzJt0f5A) about using TensorBoard.</sub>